# optimizing a Flash swf with lots of movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wrote an app that uses lots of sprites that are created at run-time. The app runs great on the PC, but I still would like to optimize it as best as I could. Here is an example of a function that creates these sprites. I am wondering if CachsAsBitmap is my solution, or if there is something else that I should consider trying. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
    function createClips(){
        for (var i:uint=0;i<100;i++){
        c = new Sprite;
        label_txt = new TextField;
        bc.graphics.beginFill(colorOf, alphaOf);
        bc.graphics.drawRect(label_x, label_y, labelWidth, labelHeight);
        bc.graphics.endFill();
        bc.mouseChildren = true;
        bc.buttonMode = true;
        label_txt.width = _width
        label_txt.height = _height
        label_txt.x = _x
        label_txt.y = _y
        label_txt.multiline = true;
        label_txt.wordWrap = true;
        label_txt.border = false;
              }
        }
```

Each of these sprites has an eventlistener that listens for certain things. Thse hold different values depending on what the user is doing. When the user selects a different screen, I remove them along with their eventlisteners via another function.

Thanks for any tips

Comment: If you mean each of them has a enterframe listener then you need to change that completely and use only one listener for all of them.

Comment: @BotMaster No, they do not have enterframe eventListeners. They have MouseEvent.ON_CLICK events. There is only event for all of them

Comment: You want to optimize for what platform? Pure desktop or other?

Comment: @BotMaster Yes, Pure Desktop.

Comment: You said everything runs great so why do you think this particular code area needs improving?

Comment: @BotMaster Well, just hoping to make it better. Additionally, the application might in the future target the mobile platform, so any optimizations made now can help down the road. Thank you